# Express js flow behavior

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I need to understand how flow works in an Express app using Routes,
I have These Routes

```
app.use(require('./routes/reportsRouter'));
app.use(require('./routes/crewsRouter'));
app.use(require('./routes/api'));
app.use(require('./routes/filesRouter'));
```

Now in ./routes/crewsRouter  I have th following Code

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router(); 
router.use(function(req, res, next) {

  var url = req.url;
  //..... Edit URL if Contains // empty parm 
  // crews//today; correct Url crews/all/today
  // this give me a list of all jobs for all crews for today. 
  console.log("CrewsRouter: ", req.method + ".( " + url + " )");
  next(); 
});
router.get('/crews', function(req, res) {
    if (!req.params.key) { next(); }
    res.render('crewsView',{
        pageTitle:'All-Crews',
        pageID:'crews', 
        crewInfo: {"aka": "all"},
        reqOptions: ''
    });

});
router.get('/crews/:leadId?/:options?', function(req, res) {....}
module.exports = router;
```

and in reportsRouter.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.use(function(req, res, next) {

    // log each request to the console
    console.log("ReportsRouter: ", req.method + ".( " + req.url + " )");
    // continue doing what we were doing and go to the route
    next(); 
});

router.get('/reports', function(req, res) {
    //var data = req.app.get('appData')

    res.render('reportsView',{
        pageTitle:'Reports',
        pageID:'reports'        
    });
});
module.exports = router;
```

The behavior I'm having is no matter what route I request 
both of the `route.use` is running. Is this normal and what can i do to stop this behavior.

Comment: *"Now in ./routes/crewsRouter I have th following Code"* That code contains syntax errors, presumably because you trimmed it for posting. Please make sure you have a *working* [mcve] you can post, so people know the syntax errors aren't the problem (and can replicate it locally).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let crewsRouter = require('routes/crewsRouter');
...

app.use('/crews', crewsRouter);
app.use('/reports', reportsRouter);
```

# crews

```
...
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    ... # this used to be your '/crews' handler
}
```

# reports

```
...
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    ... # this used to be your '/reports' handler
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably be doing something like this:

```
app.use('/reports', require('./routes/reportsRouter'));
app.use('/crews', require('./routes/crewsRouter'));
app.use('/api', require('./routes/api'));
app.use('/files', require('./routes/filesRouter'));
```

And then in your `reportsRouter`:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.use(function(req, res, next) {

    // log each request to the console
    console.log("ReportsRouter: ", req.method + ".( " + req.url + " )");
    // continue doing what we were doing and go to the route
    next(); 
});

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    //var data = req.app.get('appData')

    res.render('reportsView',{
        pageTitle:'Reports',
        pageID:'reports'        
    });
});
module.exports = router;
```

And your `crewsRouter`:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router(); 
router.use(function(req, res, next) {

  var url = req.url;
  //..... Edit URL if Contains // empty parm 
  // crews//today; correct Url crews/all/today
  // this give me a list of all jobs for all crews for today. 
  console.log("CrewsRouter: ", req.method + ".( " + url + " )");
  next(); 
});
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    if (!req.params.key) { return next(); }
    res.render('crewsView',{
        pageTitle:'All-Crews',
        pageID:'crews', 
        crewInfo: {"aka": "all"},
        reqOptions: ''
    });
});
router.get('/:leadId?/:options?', function(req, res) {....});
module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Thank for the Answers. I made the above change. I will do some Testing to see if the  Route.use still runs on all routes